# General Android learning

Tags: android, syntax, structure

I just started learning Android developing using an Android Studio program, i am using video tutorials and reading lots of Google developing sites, but a common problem in all of the tutorials is that everyone showing how to write Java codes but they all know what method to write or to be exec they all know the structure of that code and methods and all that is related to it.
So my question is basically: how to know what code to write and what structure to use in that code/method.
Thank`s in advance.

Comment: By learning on your own through documentation or from others who already know that write tutorials.

Comment: If you're asking where the android developer documentation is-  developer.android.com.  If you just need to learn android, go there.  If you're asking for how to write/architect a Java program in general, you're WAY too broad for this site.

Comment: "how to know what code to write and what structure to use in that code/method" ??  that comes with 50% knowledge and 50% experiance